# How to keep labels inside the box in BarChart3D

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

The following code

```
BarChart3D[
 Map[Labeled[#, Text[Style[#, Black, Opacity[1.], Bold, 20]], 
    Above] &, {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 1}}, {2}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> Large,
 ChartElements -> Graphics3D[Cylinder[]],
 ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3]], 
 AxesLabel -> {None, None, None},
 Ticks -> {None, None, {0, 1, 2}},
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"O", "E", "R", "N"}, Axis], {"D", "N", "A"}},
 ViewPoint -> {1.3`, -2.4`, 2.`}]
```

Works an place labels near axis. And what's interesting is that as you move the box, i.e. change the ViewPoint, with your mouse, the labels change accordingly.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, there is something happening at the UI level with that positioning; and I couldn't find an option to place labels that worked for longer text. I need this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

to have labels properly placed. The chart labels are:

```
....
ChartLabels -> {
   Placed[{"Osteo", "Ewing", "Rhabdo", "Neuro"},  Axis],
   {"Dele", "Norm", "Ampl"}}
....
```

So, how to tell *Mathematica* to place labels on `Axis` but aligned properly?

**Note:** `Placed[...,Axis]` is the default; so I put it above just in case that rings a bell to someone.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for asking. `BarChart3D` rotate the labels as you change the point of view. The 3D position and overall size seem ok for very short labels as shown in first picture, but for longer labels it seems there is not enough room to display and they overflow the bottom plane. It is a little bit pedantic on my side, I am afraid, but if there is an option to change some position or size I am willing to spend some time perfecting the drawing ;-)

Comment: Does `PlotRangePadding -> .5` fix your problem?

Comment: It does! @Kuba, you should post it as answer; happy to accept it. `PlotRangePadding -> .35` is just perfect :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you can upvote answers you accepted too. Not that I need it very much :p but I've seen I'm not the only one that was accepted by you with score `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust `PlotRangePadding`:

Without:

[image]

And with `PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, 0}`
[image]

p.s. both with `BaseStyle -> {Bold, 18}`